# How to compare between two values in one field depending on another field in SQL* / Oracle Reports?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sqlplus, oraclereports

I have three fields in a table named `table_family`.

One is "relation" it has 3 kinds of values 1 for person, 2 for parents, 3 for son.

Other field is "age" and it contains the ages of all the relations in the first table.

The 3rd field is for the family number.

Now the relation could be repeated like four sons and two parents for the same family
This is an example:

```
Family   Relation   Age

1         1          25

1         2          40

1         2          35

1         3          30

1         3          28

1         3          29

2         1          30

2         2          40

2         3          12
```

Now I want to build a report that displays an error which is:
Whenever the difference between parent (relation=2) and son (relation=3) is less than 12, then this is an error.

I tried this code :

```
select family from table_family
group by family
having
SELECT  family

FROM table_FAMILY 

GROUP BY 

     family
HAVING
((
 MAX(DECODE ( relation,2,age ))  
-  MAX(DECODE ( relation,3,age ))
 ) 
 <12 )
 OR
 (
 (SELECT MIN(age) FROM table_FAMILY WHERE relation=2) -(SELECT MIN(age) FROM       table_FAMILY WHERE relation=3) < 12

 )
```

If I use this code then only the maximum and minimum values will be compared. The values in between will be ignored but I need them to be compared in the same way.

The output report will be something like:

```
family  difference between parent and son

1               10

1               12

1               11

1                5

1                7

1                6
```

This what I need in the final report

For family = 1 I subtracted parent age - son age =

40-30=10

40-28=12

40-29=11

35-30=5

35-28=7

35-29=6

But for the 2nd family

40-12= 28 >12 then should not be listed (not an error).

Any help please?

Comment: I don't get this, does family 1 have two different fathers? How do you know which one who is the father to the three different sons?

Comment: family 1 has father and mother (relation =2) and three sons(relation =3) and so on for family 2 has one father and one son

Comment: can you display your desired output of it(your given example) .....as its not clear of your comment in first answer ... as far as the query compare the parent age to each of its child ...

Comment: I put the final output in my question hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
select *
from table_family f1 join table_family f2 on f1.family = f2.family
where f1.relation = 2 and f2.relation = 3
 and f1.age - f2.age <= 12
```

Comment: This won't work because for example f1.age can have 2 values only and f2.age can have 4 values then the compare will happen in the same records only and what I want is to compare each parent with each son and whenever the difference is less than 12 then this is a report.